# I want to change specific text color inside the ace-editor

Tags: angular5, angular7, ace-editor

i want to change the specific text to some colors inside ace-editor

```
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodGetNoParams] : Method [GET]
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Request []
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Method [POST]
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Request-Headers []
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Response
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Method [DELETE]
```

above is dynamic generated code inside the ace-editor i want to change colors to Method[GET] to red and Method[post] to Blue and something for Method[put] and Method[delete]

i tried by writing like this and using class property as well

```
this.editor.getEditor().getSession().addMarker(new Range(2, 2, 2, 6), 
"foo", "ace_active-line");
editor.container.classList.add("myEditor")

.myEditor{
color: blue;
background-color: aqua;
}
```

i want to change Text Color inside ace-editor like above mention i want to change colors for different method GET POST Delete and put i tried but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

If this is not embedded in other code and is a separate file, you can create a new Mode

```js
// define a mode for highlighting logs
ace.define("ace/mode/my-log-mode", function(require, exports, module) {
    
var oop = require("ace/lib/oop");
var TextHighlightRules = require("ace/mode/text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;
var TextMode = require("./text").Mode;
var LogHighlightRules = function() {
    this.$rules = {
        "start" : [{
            token : "keyword",
            regex : /Method \[(?:POST|GET|)\]/,
        }], 
    };
};
oop.inherits(LogHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

var Mode = function() {
    this.HighlightRules = LogHighlightRules;
};
oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

(function() {
}).call(Mode.prototype);

exports.Mode = Mode;
});

// set mode to the editor
editor = ace.edit("log", {
  mode: "ace/mode/my-log-mode"
});
```

```html
<script src=http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js></script>
<div id=log style="height:500px">DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodGetNoParams] : Method [GET]
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Request []
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Method [POST]
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Request-Headers []
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Response
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Method [DELETE]</div>
```

You can learn more about modes from https://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter

Comment: but this is dynamic generated code 

logText=`DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodGetNoParams] : Method [GET]
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Request []
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Method [POST]
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Request-Headers []
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Response
DEBUG [ApiV1AutocodeGetNoParams] : Method [DELETE]`;

Comment: I've editor the answer to make it less confusing, the way you set the value of the editor (logText in the previous version of my answer) is not related to the mode, set the value of the editor anyway you want

Comment: still  i did not find any answer